# Multicollinearity in levels and changes (regression analysis)

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation

I am wondering, is it possible that when conducting a multiple regression analysis by using levels, there is a relatively high multicollinearity (over 75%) but when having all the variables in changes, there is no high multicollinearity (less than 20%)?

In other words, is it possible that the correlation disappears when changing from levels to changes/differences?

Comment: Please explain what it means to "have all the variables in changes."  The meaning of this phrase is obscure.  Note, too, that 0.75% = 0.0075 is tiny.  Perhaps you mean 75%?  And what exactly does that measure?

Comment: I mean that every variable is in form εt=Yt-Yt-1. And yes, sorry, I mean 75% which measures correlation.

Comment: Or should I write εt=Y(t)-Y(t-1)